# Create a listing using etsy api from a desktop application

Tags: c#, wpf, api

I am developing a desktop application from where the user can create the listings using the etsy api. As per the etsy support, you don't need full access if one is accessing his own shop. Yet, I get the following error:
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

here is the code:

```
var baseUrl = "http://openapi.etsy.com/v2/listings";
   restClient = new RestClient(baseUrl);
   oAuth = new OAuthBase();           
   e1 = new Etsy_portal(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
   string str = e1.GetConfirmUrl(out AccessToken, out AccessTokenSecret);
   e1.ObtainTokenCredentials(AccessToken, AccessTokenSecret, verifiedToken, out PAccessToken, out PAccessTokenSecret);
   string nonce = oAuth.GenerateNonce();
   string timeStamp = oAuth.GenerateTimeStamp();
   string normalizedUrl;
   string normalizedRequestParameters;
   string sig = oAuth.GenerateSignature(new Uri(baseUrl + MethodLocation), consumerKey, consumerSecret, PAccessToken, PAccessTokenSecret,
                        "Post", timeStamp, nonce, 
   OAuth.OAuthBase.SignatureTypes.HMACSHA1, out normalizedUrl, out normalizedRequestParameters);
   restClient = new RestClient(baseUrl);
   var request = new RestRequest();

   request.AddParameter("api_key", consumerKey);
   request.AddParameter("oauth_consumer_key", consumerKey);
   request.AddParameter("oauth_token", PAccessToken);
   request.AddParameter("oauth_nonce", nonce);
   request.AddParameter("oauth_timestamp", timeStamp);
   request.AddParameter("oauth_signature", sig);
   request.AddParameter("oauth_signature_method", "HMAC-SHA1");
   request.AddParameter("oauth_version", "1");

   request.AddParameter("title", "This is a test");
   request.AddParameter("description", "Test Description");
   request.AddParameter("quantity", "1");
   request.AddParameter("price", "5");
   request.AddParameter("is_supply", "false");
   request.AddParameter("when_made", "2010_2017");
   request.AddParameter("who_made", "i_did");
   request.Method = Method.POST;

           IRestResponse resRes = restClient.Execute(request);
```

Comment: It would be best to include the code in your original post if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var baseUrl = "http://openapi.etsy.com/v2/listings";
    restClient = new RestClient(baseUrl);
    oAuth = new OAuthBase();
    e1 = new Etsy_portal(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
    string str = e1.GetConfirmUrl(out AccessToken, out AccessTokenSecret);
    e1.ObtainTokenCredentials(AccessToken, AccessTokenSecret, verifiedToken, out PAccessToken, out PAccessTokenSecret);
    sigHasher = new HMACSHA1(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(string.Format("{0}&{1}", consumerSecret, PAccessTokenSecret)));
    string nonce = oAuth.GenerateNonce();
    string timeStamp = oAuth.GenerateTimeStamp();
    string normalizedUrl;
    string normalizedRequestParameters;
    var data = new Dictionary<string, string> {
        { "title", "This is a test1" },
        { "description", "Test Description1" },
        { "quantity", "1" },
        { "price", "5" },
        { "is_supply", "false" },
        { "state", "draft" },
        { "when_made", "2010_2017" },
        { "who_made", "i_did" },
        { "shipping_template_id", "43862539760" }
    };


    data.Add("oauth_consumer_key", consumerKey);
    data.Add("oauth_signature_method", "HMAC-SHA1");
    data.Add("oauth_timestamp", timeStamp);
    data.Add("oauth_nonce", nonce); // Required, but Twitter doesn't appear to use it, so "a" will do.
    data.Add("oauth_token", PAccessToken);
    data.Add("oauth_version", "1.0");
    data.Add("oauth_signature", GenerateSignature(baseUrl, data));
    string oAuthHeader = GenerateOAuthHeader(data);
    var formData = new FormUrlEncodedContent(data.Where(kvp => !kvp.Key.StartsWith("oauth_")));
    using (var http = new HttpClient())
    {
        http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", oAuthHeader);
        var httpResp = http.PostAsync(baseUrl, formData);
        var respBody = httpResp.Result;

    }
```